# Salesforce Marketing Cloud - Roles and Permissions Issue

Tags: marketing-cloud, permissions, roles

Typically for a power user in SFMC I will assign the following roles:

- Administrator
- Marketing Cloud Administrator

Historically this has given access to 95% of the areas needed.

The issue is now that I'm trying to modify the permissions slightly, I'm noticing that many of the areas users have access to with these roles, is actually showing as 'Denied' when reviewing user permissions. This makes it extremely difficult to judge the current level of access the user has.

Example: A user has the two roles above and it claims I should be 'Denied' on all of these Data Extension permissions, which is not the case:

[image]

Is this an interface glitch or am I missing something?

Comment: I believe this might be a glitch, as ADMINISTRATOR and MARKETING CLOUD ADMINISTRATOR roles are system defined and cannot be edited!........ However, you can re-confirm this by trying to create a Data Extension with that specific user login.

Comment: Yes I definitely have those permissions. I am trying to figure out specific combinations, like what a Content Creator + Analyst + Custom Role would have access to, but this interface is looking completely unreliable. Basically forcing me to test out with a test user and trial/error.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is an interface glitch. I have painstakingly replicated the checkboxes for *Administrator* and *Marketing Cloud Administrator* using the individual permissions and it does not mirror the system defined roles. I do not get the same access as I do unless I use the system denied roles. There must be permissions that are not visible in the user interface.

For reference: [Marketing Cloud User Permissions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_enterprise_user_permissions.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) and [Roles](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_roles.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null)

Answer (score 0):

Check your user's individual permission, someone may have have denied this permission to this user. and individual permission will always overwrite roles permission.

Comment: Thanks @pankaj, it is odd, their individual permissions had package manager showing as allowed even though it isn't selected. By changing it to deny and unselecting package manager, the permission seems to then remain as denied.